# Merging 2 arrays with different keys but same value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, key

these are my arrays

```
test = {[0:Jose Rodriguez, 1:Offline], [ 0:Shen Cruz, 1:Offline]}

test2 = {[name:Shen Cruz,address:Pasay]}


]}
```

This is the output i want to have:

```
test3 = {[name:Shen Cruz,address:Pasay,1:Offline]}
```

How can I merged this two with using different key which is 0 and name but two same values in javascript.

Comment: `{[ 0:Jose Rodriguez, 1:Offline], [ 0:Shen Cruz, 1:Offline] }` - this isn't a valid javascript array?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because data structures (objects) used are not valid JavaScript objects

Answer (score 0):

This is a dictionary, or JS Object

```
{'key':'value'}
```

This is a list

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

What you have is neither. You can't assign a key to something inside a list. Only objects can do that.

You could do

```
[{'key1': 'value1'},{'key2': 'value2'},{'otherKey': 'otherValue'}]
```

or

```
{'people':{'name': 'Shen Cruz', 'address': 'Pasay'}}
```